# Custom ordering before regular ordering?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar (256) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO items (id, title) VALUES (1, 'qux');
INSERT INTO items (id, title) VALUES (2, 'quux');
INSERT INTO items (id, title) VALUES (3, 'quuz');
INSERT INTO items (id, title) VALUES (4, 'corge');
INSERT INTO items (id, title) VALUES (5, 'grault');

CREATE TABLE last_used (
    item_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES items (id),
    date integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO last_used (item_id, date) VALUES (2, 1000);
INSERT INTO last_used (item_id, date) VALUES (3, 2000);
INSERT INTO last_used (item_id, date) VALUES (2, 3000);

CREATE TABLE rating (
    item_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES items (id),
    rating integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO rating (item_id, rating) VALUES (1, 400);
INSERT INTO rating (item_id, rating) VALUES (2, 100);
INSERT INTO rating (item_id, rating) VALUES (3, 200);
INSERT INTO rating (item_id, rating) VALUES (4, 300);
INSERT INTO rating (item_id, rating) VALUES (5, 500);
```

I want to select rows in the following order:

1. Last used items matching the search string;
2. Most rated items matching the search string;
3. All other items matching the search string.

For the search `i.title ~* '(?=.*u)'`, I get:

```
   id   |   title   |   max(last_used.date)   |   rating.rating   
   3    |   quuz    |          2000           |        200
   2    |   quux    |          3000           |        100
   5    |   grault  |          null           |        500
   1    |   qux     |          null           |        400
```

…with the following code:

```
WITH used AS (
    SELECT lu.item_id
        FROM last_used lu
    JOIN (
        SELECT item_id, max(date) AS date
        FROM last_used
        GROUP BY 1
    ) sub USING (date)
 -- WHERE lu.user_id = 1
    ORDER BY lu.date DESC
)
SELECT i.id, i.title, r.rating
    FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN rating r
        ON r.item_id = i.id
    WHERE
        i.title ~* '(?=.*u)'
    ORDER BY
        i.id NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM used),
        r.rating DESC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Is it possible to get the following results (latest used items first)?

```
   id   |   title   |   max(last_used.date)   |   rating.rating   
   2    |   quux    |          3000           |        100
   3    |   quuz    |          2000           |        200
   5    |   grault  |          null           |        500
   1    |   qux     |          null           |        400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the desired order

through the `ORDER BY` clause with `l.date DESC NULLS LAST, r.rating DESC NULLS LAST`:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, l.date, r.rating
    FROM items i
    LEFT JOIN rating r
        ON r.item_id = i.id
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_id, max(date) AS date FROM last_used GROUP BY 1 ) l
        ON l.item_id = i.id        
    WHERE
        i.title ~* '(?=.*u)'
    ORDER BY l.date DESC NULLS LAST, r.rating DESC NULLS LAST
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3a7a8ca7a5e42d162c6d1c7160a0cb1c)</kbd>